# member function isn't a function error

Tags: javascript

With this code:

```
function thing(){
    function majig(){
        alert("done");
    }
}
var mything = new thing();
mything.majig();
```

I'm getting this error:
TypeError: mything.majig is not a function

I've done javascript for some time, and I've done functions as part of functions and called them before. I know it has to be something simple I'm missing or forgetting, but various websearches (and poking around here) are getting me deeper theory answers, or examples that seem to indicate that this should work.

I know TypeError: *foo* is not a function usually means a syntax error. I've looked up examples, and it *looks* like I have the syntax right (I've tried a few variations with no success).

It's got to be some dumb simple mistake, but I'm just not catching it right now. What do I do in my function to make the `mything.majig();` run properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared a function in `thing`, but it's not attached to `this` at all. Try this:

```
function thing(){
    this.majig = function() {
        alert("done");
    }
}

var mything = new thing();
mything.majig();
```

Alternately:

```
function thing() {
  return {
    majig: function() {
      alert("done");
    }
  };
}
```

Or, better yet:

```
function thing() { }
thing.prototype.majig = function () {
  alert('done');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is not what you think it means. It's not a member declaration. It's an inner function. Inner functions work just like local variables - they're only accessible in the scope of the outer function:

```
function foo () {
    function bar () {}
    bar(); // accessible here
}
bar(); // undefined here
```

If your function is a constructor, then to add a member function to the object that it constructs you'd add it to the constructor's prototype:

```
function Foo () {}
Foo.prototype.bar = function () {}; // bar is a member of object Foo

var f = new Foo();
f.bar(); // call member function
```

Objects in javascript are dynamic. They behave more like maps/hashes do in other languages. This means you can add a member function directly to an object instead of a constructor's prototype:

```
var f = {};
f.bar = function () {};

f.bar(); // call member function
```

Following the logic above, since `this` in a constructor refers to the object being constructed, you can also dynamically add a function to `this`. This is typically called "decoration" since it is effectively an ad-hoc version of the decorator design pattern:

```
function Foo () {
    this.bar = function () {}
}

var f = new Foo();
f.bar();
```